# How to log how many possibilities fulfil the if statement javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

```js
const grades = [9, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6];
for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
  if (grades[i] >= 8) {
    console.log(grades[i])
  }
}
```

I'm trying to log how many items from the array fulfil the condition. the output I'm looking for is : 6 (because 6 of the numbers are equal or greater than 8)

tried

let count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {

if (grades[i]>= 8){
count++

```
console.log(count)

}
```

}

Comment: Just keep a counter in the for loop and output the result after it

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: array filter();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function countGreaterThan8(grades){
    // initialize the counter
    let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {

      // if the condition satisfied counter will be incremented 1
      if (grades[i] >= 8) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
    return counter;
}

const grades = [9, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6];
console.log(countGreaterThan8(grades)); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Array.filter` to create a new array containing only items that fulfill the condition. You can then make use of the length of the array however you want. Like this

```
const grades = [9, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 9, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 5, 6];
const gradesThatPassCondition = grades.filter(grade => grade > 6);
console.log(gradesThatPassCondition.length);
```